# How to load a table from a databse in synapse to default(spark)?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am trying to load a table sitting in a database in synapse azure to default(spark) so that i can call the table to run the respective pandas code. However i am not able to do it.

```
%%spark
val df = spark.read.sqlanalytics("emea***********.rpt.Vw_APInvoices") 
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("default.t1")
```

Error:

```
Error : com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.exception.SQLAnalyticsConnectorException: The specified table does not exist. Please provide a valid table.
  at com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.read.SQLAnalyticsReader.readSchema(SQLAnalyticsReader.scala:103)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Relation$.create(DataSourceV2Relation.scala:175)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:204)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SqlAnalyticsConnector$SQLAnalyticsFormatReader.sqlanalytics(SqlAnalyticsConnector.scala:42)
  ... 52 elided
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error message clearly says - `The specified table does not exist. Please provide a valid table.`

```
Error : com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.exception.SQLAnalyticsConnectorException: The specified table does not exist. Please provide a valid table.
```

> Make sure specified table exists before you running above code.

[image]

**Reference:** [Azure Synapse Analytics - Load the NYC Taxi data into the Spark nyctaxi database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-spark#load-the-nyc-taxi-data-into-the-spark-nyctaxi-database).